# What happens when we do cout<<string?

Tags: c++, string, vector

Consider we have declared a string like this: `string x;` and a vector of chars like this: `vector<char> x_vec;`
I was thinking if there is any advantage of doing

```
cout<<x;
```

Over

```
for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++)
      cout<<x[i];
```

Or

```
for(int i=0;i<x_vec.size();i++)
      cout<<x_vec[i];
```

in *performance*? My point is because very often we get to the point where we must choose between `string`s and `vector`s of chars. Is the first example actually treated or approached by the program differently from the other examples?

Comment: What exactly are you doing where you frequently have to choose between strings and vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a distinct advantage of using

```
out << str;
```

over the loops writing characters invidivually: the formatted output operators, including those for `char` create a `std::ostream::sentry` object for each output. Also, since the stream doesn't know that you just wrote a character the stream, it needs to recheck its internal state. If you want to profile writing sequences of characters compared to the above formatted output, you should use something like

```
out.write(str.c_str(), str.size());
```

or

```
std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(out));
```

I would expect that the formatted output and the version using `write()` are about the same performance and the vesion using `std::copy()` is probably slower although there is no good reason that it has to be slower other than standard C++ libraries not bothering with creating a fast implementation: I know that it can be done efficiently mainly because I did it for my [experimental standard C++ library implementation](http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/cxxrt/).

Answer (score 6):

> My point is because very often we get to the point where we must choose between strings and vectors of chars.

Very often? I don't think so.

If something is fundamentally a string, just use `std::string`.

*If and when* you can prove that performance is suboptimal (usually by profiling your program on real data), then consider alternatives. `std::vector<char>` is one such alternative, but there are others. Which, if any, would be preferable depends on the actual use case.

In all likelihood it'll be a while before you encounter a compelling real-world case for replacing `std::string` with `std::vector<char>`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a loop in all three cases - in the first case, it's inside the implementation of `operator <<` which calls the OS which does looping, while in the other two cases it is in your code.

The last two cases are identical in terms of performance, if not in terms of generated code: both strings and vectors use contiguous storage, so their `operator []`s are extremely fast.

The first case, where the loop belongs in the implementation of the operator, may be optimized better when the implementation calls through to the underlying operating system. The most important point, however, is readability: a single line with a simple statement always reads better than even a simple loop.

In general, the biggest difference between strings and vectors of `char`s is the set of primitives supported by the two containers: strings are geared toward conveying string-like semantics (making substrings, simple searches), while vectors are better to convey array-like semantics (sequential collections of items with fast access to an arbitrary index). In terms of performance, the two structures are very similar.